# How to search for arbitrage opportunities?

Tags: bsc, full-node, arbitrage

Noticed some arbitrageurs playing around.

For example, this tx (swap BUSD for ETH https://bscscan.com/tx/0xdebf81a126249386d15ae003006f7b7862087aecf3ef9775a5f1d0bae10e6047) opened an arbitrage opportunity. The next transaction (by position in the same block https://bscscan.com/tx/0x14b7cbfc190a914d204d1b262e8cfc0e07d702538ee00ff27cc22d3ef83f63f1) has rapidly closed it.

My question is how do they manage to put their tx just right after the target one? I don't believe they use MEW on BSC. Of course, they gotta have their own BSC node, but what else? Or it's pretty enough for such rapid reaction?

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrage opportunities can be potentially created using MEV (Maximal Extractable Value) Bots. There are repositories that can be referenced in creating one. Here is one:

https://github.com/paco0x/amm-arbitrageur/blob/master/contracts/FlashBot.sol

Comment: I'm not sure Flashbots are operating on BSC

Answer (score -1):

I have an article on medium about it:

https://medium.com/p/526bac2bb536

You don't need a full node. Just a script that check price on each block.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting

However I have some points I wouldn't agree.

1) Full-node is a must for competitive markets as arbitrageurs are tracking mempool transactions to find potential arbitrage opportunities, private node also grants faster speeds.

2) Your contract is not considering swap size, as it is strictly bound to the amount available on the wallet. Calculating a proper swap amount is a key to the profitable strategy.

Comment: The contract doesn't but the backend script do calculate swap size.